# how to use a parent class as a parameter in an inherited child class in c++?

Tags: c++

it could be not good question and i know i need more time to learn about it 
but i'm really wondering how to make it work 
here is my code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Parent{
    protected:
        int value;
        int size;
    public:
        Parent();
        Parent(const Parent &p);
};
Parent::Parent()
{
    this->value = 0;
    this->size = 0;
}
Parent::Parent(const Parent &p)
{
    this->value = p.value;
    this->size = p.size;
}
class Child:public Parent{
    public:
        Child();
        Child(const Parent& p);
};
Child::Child()
{
    this->value = 0;
    this->size = 0;
}
Child::Child(const Parent& p)
{
    this->value = ??
    this->size = ?? 
}
```

as i want  to use parent class as a parameter in an inherited child class,
the problem is i can't use p.size or p.value in child class. 
is there any way to solve this problem? 
thank u for read this.

Comment: what is "this problem" ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number as i want to use p.size or p.value but it's not working.

Comment: "it's not working" - please clarify. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @anatolyg as i compiled it, it said can't access to protected value

Comment: @J.K You can turn your code into [mcve] by a few minor fixes. This will help people answer your question and also will help you understand and use their answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `Child(const Parent& p);` is not a proper copy constructor. A copy constructor for a class `T` takes a `&T` (possibly with CV-qualifier) as argument. In this case it should be `Child(const Child& p);`.

Furthermore, if we look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access, then we can see that:

> A protected member of a class is only accessible
>
> 1. to the members and
>    friends of that class;
> 2. to the members and friends (until C++17) of
>    any derived class of that class, but only when the class of the object
>    through which the protected member is accessed is that derived class
>    or a derived class of that derived class

So a function in `Child` that takes a `Child` as argument has access to that other `Child`s protected members, but a function that takes a `Parent` does not have access to that `Parent`s protected members.

For example, if you have a `Button` and `TextBox` that both inherit from `UIWidget`, then the `Button` can access `UIWidget` protected members in other `Button`s, but not in `TextBox`es.

Edit:

If you really want to have a constructor that takes a `Parent` as argument, then you can do as Roy Avidan suggests in his answer, and do this:

```
Child::Child(const Parent& p)
: Parent(p)  // <- Call the Parent copy constructor
{
  // No access to protected members of p here!
}
```

This works because it calls the copy constructor of `Parent` with a `Parent` argument, which means that any access to the protected members of `Parent` happens in `Parent`. Note that any access to a protected member of `p` in the body is an access violation of `p`.

Comment: i know what u mean ,then it is impossible to use parent class in child class like that way?

Comment: I have made an edit with more some more explanations

Comment: thanks then seems like there is no way to access it.

Answer (score 6):

When you implement a class, you also have to use its constructors in each of your derived class constructors.

In your case: `Child::Child(const Parent& p) : Parent(p) {}`

Comment: it's not working. i mean it said it's not allowed to access protected value

Comment: Works for me. I think it's the correct answer.